# how to display data in shapeableimageview from firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase

**Given**:method of receiving data which for some reason does not work.  adapter for using SwipeCard koloda library
**Goal**: load photo and name from folder in firebase into shapeableimageview and textview respectively
**Problem**: the method of receiving data does not work and the name and photo are not loaded from the folder.
Adapter:

```
public class SwipeAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context;

    private List<Integer> list;

    public SwipeAdapter(Context context,List<Integer>list) {

        this.context=context;

        this.list=list;

    }

    @Override

    public int getCount() {

        return 20;

    }

    @Override

    public Object getItem(int i) {

        return null;

    }

    @Override

    public long getItemId(int i) {

        return 0;

    }

    @Override

    public View getView(int i, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

     View view;

     if(convertView==null)

     {

         view= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_koloda,parent,false);

     }else {

         view=convertView;

     }

     return view;

    }

   

}
```

Activity with a receive method

```
private SwipeAdapter adapter;

private List<Integer> list;

private TextView nameusercard;

private ShapeableImageView imageosnovnoe;

Koloda koloda;

    @Override

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        koloda=findViewById(R.id.koloda);

        list=new ArrayList<>();

        adapter=new SwipeAdapter(this,list);

        koloda.setAdapter(adapter);

        nameusercard=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.nameusercard);

        imageosnovnoe=(ShapeableImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageosnovnoe);

    }

private void getUserWInfo()

{

    DatabaseReference reference= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()

            .child("Userw");

    reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

        @Override

        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

            if (snapshot.exists()&&snapshot.getChildrenCount()>0)

            {

                String name=snapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();

                nameusercard.setText(name);

                if (snapshot.hasChild("image")) {

                    String image = snapshot.child("image").getValue().toString();

                    Picasso.get().load(image).into(imageosnovnoe);

                }

            }

        }

        @Override

        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }

    });

}

}
```

Xml item_koloda

```
LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

    android:orientation="vertical"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"

    android:layout_gravity="center"

    android:gravity="center"

    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView

        android:layout_width="match_parent"

        android:layout_height="500dp"

        android:layout_margin="15dp"

        app:cardCornerRadius="15dp"

        app:cardElevation="5dp">

        <LinearLayout

            android:id="@+id/linearmain"

            android:layout_width="match_parent"

            android:layout_height="400dp"

            android:orientation="vertical">

            <com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView

                android:id="@+id/imageosnovnoe"

                android:layout_width="match_parent"

                android:layout_height="400dp"

                android:backgroundTint="@color/white"

                android:scaleType="fitXY"

                app:srcCompat="@drawable/aaaaa" />

        </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout

                android:id="@+id/linearhori"

                android:layout_width="match_parent"

                android:layout_height="100dp"

                android:orientation="horizontal"

                android:layout_gravity="bottom"

                android:weightSum="3">

                <ImageView

                    android:id="@+id/like"

                    android:layout_width="90dp"

                    android:layout_height="90dp"

                    android:layout_gravity="center"

                    android:layout_weight="1"

                    android:src="@drawable/sas"

                    />

                <ImageView

                    android:id="@+id/disslike"

                    android:layout_width="90dp"

                    android:layout_height="90dp"

                    android:layout_gravity="center"

                    android:layout_weight="1"

                    android:src="@drawable/aan"

                    />

            </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

I tried to register the method in the adapter but it didn't work either.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?

Comment: no photo acceptance, shapeableimageview empty in textview no info from firebase